# How to show timestamp from iPhone voice memo

Tags: voice-memo

I need the time stamp from my voice memo on my iPhone 7s to dispute a mv ticket. How can I gain access to this information?

Voice memos only show the length of a recording but I also need the exact time of the recording.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I did find a way to discover the date and time the voice memo was created, perhaps there are easier ways, but this works.

1. On your iPhone in the Voice Memos app select the recording you wish to find the date/time it was created.
2. Hit the three dots in the circle (...) on the top right.
3. Hit the Share button
4. E-mail the file to yourself
5. Open the e-mail on your PC
6. Download the voice recording file to your PC
7. Right-Click the file you downloaded and hit "Properties"
8. In the Properties menu at the top select the tab "Details"
9. Scroll down to the "Origin" section
10. You will see a label "Media created" and directly to the right of that the date and time the voice recording was created.

This process only helps you, however. You will likely need to submit your phone to a third party to do a forensic analysis for any procedural or lawyerly body to accept your digital evidence, but this will help you know if you want to spend on a proper report.

Comment: FFS............

Answer (score 1):

On recent versions of macOS, you can get the Voice Memos metadata:

```
sqlite3 "$HOME/Library/Group Containers/group.com.apple.VoiceMemos.shared/Recordings/CloudRecordings.db" -header -column "SELECT ZPATH, ZCUSTOMLABEL, ZENCRYPTEDTITLE FROM ZCLOUDRECORDING"
```

This results in output like this:

```
ZPATH                         ZCUSTOMLABEL          ZENCRYPTEDTITLE
----------------------------  --------------------  ----------------------
20180316 191536-380A9FB4.m4a  2018-03-16T18:15:36Z  New Recording
20230827 204257-CD3D14AE.m4a  2023-08-27T18:42:57Z  Recording 3
```

The `ZPATH` values are in local time as "YYYYMMDD hhmmss" and a hash and the `ZCUSTOMLABEL` values are in UTC.

Older versions of decrypted iOS backups also have a `CloudRecordings.db` file but the file location and schema differ.

Answer (score 0):

There's a utility on the Mac which will display the Recording Date/Time.

1. Download Media Meta from the [App Store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/media-meta/id1521777699?mt=12) or [website](https://www.fireebok.com/media-meta.html).
2. Export the audio note from Voice Memos.
3. Lauch Media Meta, and drag the resulting file to the Media Meta window (not icon).
4. The Recording Date field will show the date and time the note was recorded in [Zulu Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time#Time_zones).

If you pay the $20 for the full version, you can copy the recording date to the creation date of the file, but you can just copy the timecode and change the creation date using another means, such as [Terminal](https://medium.com/hackernoon/how-to-change-a-file-s-last-modified-and-creation-dates-on-mac-os-x-494f8f76cdf4) or a utility like [File Buddy](https://www.skytag.com/file_buddy/version11/).

Answer (score -1):

Since iOS 13, it's slightly easier.

1. in the Voice recording App, go to "Edit",
2. select all the recordings you want to determine the info from.
3. Click "Share" and save those files to an iCloud folder.
4. (3b). If you have no iCloud folder, save to the local device, and connect the iPhone to the PC and use the Finder to sync these files somehow -- but that's another challenge.
5. The files will be visible on your iCloud / sync'd folder with their timestamps in the listing / info fields.